# Incorrectly allinged header

Tags: php, css

Hello I am new to styling PHP -

So the issue I am facing is a misaligned part of my header [Home / login / create account / questions?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tne7e.png)

I just need assistance in floating that text that to the right so it is not off to the left like it currently is.

Here is the code

```
<?php
foreach ($_GET as $gkey => $gvalue) {

if (!is_array($gvalue)) {
    $_GET[$gkey] = stripslashes($gvalue);
}
}
?>
<div class="col-md-7 text-right sm-text-right">
<?php
if ($_COOKIE[userid] > 0) {
    echo widget('Bootstrap Theme - Header - Member                             Links','',$w[website_id],$w);

} else { ?>
    <ul class="mini-nav nomargin list-inline <?php if ($wa[custom_159] != 4) { ?>vpad<?php } ?>">
        <?php
        if ($wa[custom_148] == "1") { ?>
            <li>
                <div id="google_translate_element" style="width:127px;"></div>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', autoDisplay: false, layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL}, 'google_translate_element');
                    }
                </script>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
        echo menuArray("header_mini_nav",0,$w); ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
} ?>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php
if (($wa[custom_159] != 0 || $wa[custom_159] == "") && $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != "www.securemypayment.com") {

    if($wa[custom_159] == 4) { ?>
        [widget=Bootstrap Theme - Banner - 320_50]
        <?php
    } else {
        $featurename = '';

        if ($wa[custom_159] == 3 || $wa[custom_159] == 1 || $wa[custom_159] == 2) {
            $featurename = 'search_results';
        }
        if ($wa[custom_159] == 5) {
            $featurename = 'coupons';
        }
        if ($wa[custom_159] == 6) {
            $featurename = 'events';
        }
        if ($wa[custom_159] == 7) {
            $featurename = 'jobs';
        }
        if ($wa[custom_159] == 8) {
            $featurename = 'products';
        }
        if ($wa[custom_159] == 9) {
            $featurename = 'properties';
        }
        if ($wa[custom_159] == 10) {
            $featurename = 'classifieds';
        }
        if ($wa[custom_159] == 11) {
            $featurename = 'videos';
        }
        if ($wa[custom_159] == 12) {
            $featurename = 'blog';
        }
        if ($wa[custom_159] == 13) {
            $featurename = 'articles';
        }
        ?>
        <form action="/<?php echo $featurename; ?>" name="frm1" class="form-inline website-search">
            <?php
            if($wa[custom_159] == 3 || $wa[custom_159] == 2 || $wa[custom_159] == 5 || $wa[custom_159] == 6 || $wa[custom_159] == 7 || $wa[custom_159] == 8 || $wa[custom_159] == 9 || $wa[custom_159] == 10 || $wa[custom_159] == 11 || $wa[custom_159] == 12 || $wa[custom_159] == 13) { ?>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm bmargin sm-autosuggest">
                    <span class="input-group-addon hidden-md"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="<?php if ($wa[custom_159] == 3 || $wa[custom_159] == 1 || $wa[custom_159] == 2) { echo $label[keyword_search_default]; } else { ?>Search by Keyword...<? } ?>" value="<? if ($_GET[q]!='') { echo htmlspecialchars($_GET[q]); } ?>" name="q" class=" <? if ($wa[custom_159] == 3 || $wa[custom_159] == 1 || $wa[custom_159] == 2) { ?>member<? } else if ($wa[custom_159] != 9) { echo $featurename; } else { ?>property<? } ?>_search form-control input-sm" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            if ($wa[custom_159] == 3 || $wa[custom_159] == 1 || $wa[custom_159] == 10) { ?>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm bmargin">
                    <span class="input-group-addon hidden-md"><i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="<?=$label[location_search_default]?>" value="<? if ($_GET[location_value]!="") { echo htmlspecialchars($_GET[location_value]); } else if ($w[geocode_visitor_default]==1 && $w[geocode]==1 && $_SESSION[vdisplay]!="") { echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION[vdisplay]); } ?>" id="location_google_maps_header" name="location_value" class="googleSuggest googleLocation form-control">
                </div>
                <?php
            } ?>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-sm btn_search bmargin xs-btn-block">
        </form>
        <?php
    }
} ?>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.goog-te-gadget-simple {
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 4px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
 color: #555;
 }
 img.goog-te-gadget-icon {
 display: none;
 }
.skiptranslate.goog-te-gadget span {
 display: none;
 }
 .skiptranslate {
 font-size: 0px;
 }
 .goog-te-gadget .goog-te-combo {
 margin-bottom: -4px;
 }
.skiptranslate.goog-te-gadget select {
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 border-radius: 3px;
 font-size: 12px;
 padding: 2px;
 width: 100%;
 background: #fff;
 }
  body input.tt-hint,body input.member_search.form-control.normal-                     autosuggest-input.tt-query {
background-color: white !important;
 }
 .input-group-sm .input-group-addon .fa {
 font-size: 15px;
 }
.ul { 
 text-align: right;
 }
```

any assistance on why this is misaligned will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please can you create an [MCVE] with the rendered html (not the php) otherwise we cannot help you

Comment: Its most likely from your CSS. But its kinda hard to figure everything out without rewriting the code.